# Unable to login from dist/index.html in angular 8 and It's allowing me If I use proxy.conf.json file

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am working with index.html page from angular 8 dist folder. Unable to login through dist/index.html page. Getting the error below for login API URL. I spent two days but no luck. Please let me know If you have any solution for this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeuUQ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6NSR.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CORS enabled on your API?  If you are running from the dist folder, then you are serving your application on port 80 but your API is on 8080 which could cause a CORS issue.  You would need to enable CORS on your API.  This is implemented differently depending on your API langugage implementation.

Comment: CORS enabled on API side. The API is implemented in java. Still, I am getting this error. Any solution for that?

Comment: What does the response from the API say?  If you are using Chrome, open the Dev Tools and go to the network tab.  There you should see the failed API call (in red).  You can inspect the headers that you sent with the request in the headers tab and the response from the API in the response tab.

Comment: In response tab - It showing " Failed to load response data "

Comment: Please click the attached file urls so that you can see more in screenshots

Comment: Can you add the request payload from the header?

Comment: The request payload : { “username “ : “id”, “password” : “password” }